# I have question about using IF to update SQL column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

I'm trying to use an `IF` statement to update a column in my database.

```
if($data[chat_points] != '2001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 1 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
if($data[chat_points] != '5000'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 2 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
if($data[chat_points] != '15001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 3 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
if($data[chat_points] != '35001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 4 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
if($data[chat_points] != '45001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 5 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
if($data[chat_points] != '70001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 6 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
```

With this code, it always updates the 'user_level' to 6.

What I want here is, when the user gets 2001 chat points... update to level 1
and when they get to 5000 chat points... update to level 2, etc.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your code has no sense. It will be always `5` (when points == 70001) or `6` (all other points).

Comment: Where is `$data[chat_points]` coming from? Another query, perhaps? You can do all this in one SQL query and remove the conditional code from you PHP.

Comment: Why you then use NOT EQUAL sign? if you compare user data to some point use '==' sign.

Comment: I am sorry for my lack of experience with that, i'm still beginner for this, and $data[chat_points] is another column in my database that store users points inside.

Comment: do you have in your array 'user_level' data available?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code has no sense. It will be always 5 (when points == 70001) or 6 (all other points).

I expect there should be condition 'is lower than', so

```
if($data[chat_points] < '2001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 1 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
elseif($data[chat_points] < '5001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 2 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
elseif($data[chat_points] < '15001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 3 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
elseif($data[chat_points] < '35001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 4 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
elseif($data[chat_points] < '45001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 5 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
elseif($data[chat_points] < '70001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 6 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
```

Or better, shorter, faster...

```
$levels = [
    2001,
    5001,
    15001,
    35001,
    45001,
    70001
];

$level = 1;
foreach ($levels as $v) {
    if ($data['chat_points'] >= $v) $level++;
}

mysqli->query ("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = " . (int)$level . " WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");

if ($level <= count($levels)) {
    echo 'Needed to next level: ' . ($levels[$level - 1] - $data['chat_points']) . ' points';
} else {
    echo 'Max level';
}
```

Comment: The goal of the poster was to only have the code run a certain number of times to minimize the number of total queries on the database. In both of your code examples, your code will make a query each time, regardless of the `user_level`. This means it has **poor performance**.

Comment: @shn: where is written that he needs to minimize SQL query count? I just see there is any `chat_points` score (we don't know if incremented by 1) and the OP needs to assing certain `user_level` to his score. Nothing about number of queries, etc.

Comment: A solution not minimizing the number of queries would cause **multiple thousands of redundant queries to be performed**, so at this point any solution not minimizing the total number of queries is irresponsible.

Comment: @shn: you're probably mind-reader, I don't read that in the question... but good luck, downvoter guy ;-)

Comment: I'm just saying that any solution that introduces thousands of unwanted queries into a seemingly amateur implementation is not recommended. :)

Comment: i don't know how i can say " thank you ", but really you helped me so much with this code. last one worked fine with me and it's really better, shorter and faster than first one, really thanks.

Comment: Just FYI, the elegance of this solution is nice, but the performance of this method is literally thousands of times worse than something more similar to your original implementation.

Comment: @shn: where is written `chat_points` is incremented by 1? If it'd be incremented eg. by 3 (or as on SO, sometimes by +10, sometimes +25, sometimes -1, -2), conditions with `==` or `!=` can be always false (user can have 100.000 points, but misses the milestones). The OP marked this answer as the accepted one, so it's probably answering the question. Howgh. Sorry, it's waste of my time to discuss here with you.

Comment: @AV.Blacky: it's okay, no special 'thank you' needed :-) Glad to help you.

Comment: sorry @panther , but i have a question, what if i want show user how many points he still need to get the next level, how i can do it?

Comment: @AV.Blacky: Updated my anwser

Answer (score 0):

**If I don't misunderstood you question** then how about this way?

```
<?php
$levels = [2001=>1, 5001=>2, 15001=>3, 35001=>4, 45001=>5, 70001=>6];

if(!empty($data['chat_points']) && array_key_exists($data['chat_points'],$levels)){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = {$levels[$data['chat_points']]} WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
?>
```

Comment: This code does the same, It makes a call to DB every time it has array not empty.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Editted, how about that now :)

Answer (score 0):

We have to get then current level of user. Just one call

```
$sql = "SELECT user_level FROM boom_users WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");    
//get the current user level
$level = $mysqli->query($sql)->fetch_object()->user_level;

//compare if user approached the 2001 limit but not exceed 5000 limit 
if($data[chat_points] >= '2001' && $data[chat_points] < '5000' && $level != 1){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 1 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
```

In this case we get in if statement true only in case if user have lower user_level, if he has above we skip. 1 call to DB before and if statement is true, one more call to update.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is **broken** because all of the statements will be executed, making the level always 6.

One way to fix this without changing the code too much is to use `if else {` statements to keep only one statement from running at a time.

```
if($data[chat_points] != '2001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 1 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
} else if($data[chat_points] != '5000'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 2 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
} else if($data[chat_points] != '15001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 3 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
} else if($data[chat_points] != '35001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 4 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
} else if($data[chat_points] != '45001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 5 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
} else if($data[chat_points] != '70001'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 6 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
```

Even in this case **it will not have the intended functionality** because these statements only run at times when the number of points are exact values. The way to make it so it runs progressively, so that a user can increase their level over time is by **changing all the `!=` comparisons to `==`.**

Comment: The OPs code was broken (always level `5` or `6`), you is broken too (always level `1` or `2`).

Comment: Take note to have functional code (as mentioned below) you need to replace the `!=` to `==`. This code is the **fastest**

Answer (score -1):

That's what i whould do:

```
//compare if user approached the 2001 limit but not exceed 5000 limit 
if($data[chat_points] >= '2001' && $data[chat_points] < '5000'){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE boom_users SET user_level = 1 WHERE user_id = '{$data['user_id']}'");
}
```

Comment: Take note that to maximize performance, the query should be run only the number of times the level should be changed.

Comment: I agree with you, but the only way to minimize calls is to have current user level var available. This way we just pass this var in condition and check if the user level still has the same level so we NOT make any calls, overwize if it's less than existing point level, we make a call to DB